# Pass parameter to getter in jackson

Tags: java, jackson

I have a class that has a getter with a parameter, like this:

```
class RandomClass {
    String getName(Integer year)
}
```

The class saves names for every year, and the default `getName()` goes to the most recent year. The problem is that I need to serialize a specific (but variable) one.

Is there some way I can pass it a parameter? Or if not, would be it possible to add a field to the jackson json where I would add to it `randomClassInstance.getName(year)` ?